# Outer measure allowing only finite covers

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be the usual length function of intervals of $\mathbb R$ and set
$\overline \lambda(A) = \inf \{\sum^m_{n=1} \lambda(I_n): A_n \text{ interval and } A \subset \bigcup^m_{n=1} I_n\}$.
Consider the set $A = \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$. The usual definition of outer measure which allows countable covers in the above infimum would give a measure of $0$ to this set $A$. Which is showed by taking a countable sequence of intervals $I_n$ which contain all points in $A$ (if $(r_n)_n$ is an enumeration of $A$ then $r_n \in I_n  \forall n$) such that $\lambda(I_n) < \varepsilon \cdot 2^{-n}$.
But if we only allow finite covers its intuively clear that the length of a cover is at least $1$. I try to write down a formal argument: If a cover of $A$ were smaller than $1$, we assume wlog the cover were disjoint. But now I am stuck. How do I show that the complement of $A$ and the cover contains at least one rational number?

Comment: It seems like this result about the outer measure defined using finite covers should generalize to "the finite-cover outer measure of any set is at least the outer measure of its closure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is $S$ is a non-empty finite set  of pairwise-disjoint non-empty bounded open intervals then $$S=\{(a_i,b_i) :i=1,..,n\} \text { for some } n\in N,$$ $$\text {with } a_i<b_i\leq a_{i+1} \text { whenever } 1\leq i<n,$$  And if such an $S$ is a cover of $Q\cap [0,1]$ with $$b_1>0 \text { and } a_n<1$$ then (I): If $b_i=a_{n+1}$ whenever $1\leq i<n$, then $\sum_{t\in S}\lambda (t)=b_n-a_1>1. $ (II): If for some $i$ we have $b_i<a_{i+1}$ then $Q\cap (b_i,a_{i+1})$ is not empty but is disjoint from $\cup S$,which is a contradiction.Notice that  if we replace $Q$ with any dense subset of $[0,1], $ and we change the phrase "$b_n-a_1>1 $" to "$b_n-a_1\geq 1 $" in (I) then it still holds.

Comment: Thx. You have a small typo: it should be ...If for some $i$ we have $b_i < a_{i+1}$ then....

Comment: And in the next phrase too.Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use induction on the number of open intervals in your cover . . .

---

Specifically, prove the following statement by induction on $n$:

> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a cover of $\mathbb{Q}\cap (a, b)$ by $n$ intervals, then the sum of the diameters of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ is $>b-a$.